# Multivalued Dependencies in a database

Tags: database-design

"There are occasional situations where we design a relation schema and find it is
in BCNF, yet the relation has a kind of redundancy that is not related to FD’s.
The most common source of redundancy in BCNF schemas is an attempt to
put two or more set-valued properties of the key into a single relation"

Hi 
can anyone explain to me what they mean then they say "two or more set-valued properties of the key" What is a set-valued property?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on 4NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) has a pretty good explanation.

Comment: set-valued property?
No information about it.

Comment: The dependencies in the example are set-valued dependencies: restaurant determines the set of pizza varieties, and restaurant determines the set of delivery areas.

Comment: Why is it called set valued?

Comment: "The table has no non-key attributes because its only key is {Restaurant, Pizza Variety, Delivery Area}." So the value 'A1 Pizza' doesn't seem to be a key, does it?